# HTML5 front end framework options - can both Vaadin and Angular be used together

Tags: java, html, scala, angularjs, vaadin

I'm looking for different options (with so many available right now) that can be used to develop the a web front end that is compatible with browsers on mobile devices.

My assumption is that it has be HTML5 based. Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

I'm looking for different options and the trade-offs. Two options [Angular](http://angularjs.org/) and I recently discovered [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/download). What other frameworks should I look at ?

To be more specific - can both Vaadin and Angular be used together ?

Our server-side is in Java/Scala. Currently we are running Jetty/Camel/Websockets but may move to Play in the future.

Comment: [_Arun Gupta on Higher Productivity from Embracing HTML5 with Java EE 7_](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/gupta-1911481.html)

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin is quite strict on your page output, being just a wrapper to gwt components with a nice model and a bunch of useful features. You develop in java and the framework builds the javascript widgets for you...

This doesn't play well with generating a mostly custom-html app.

This means that, while possible, it's not advisable nor productive to mix it with Angular.

On the other end Play is practically agnostic about your front-end/view layer. You can mix it up with every possible javascript/html/rest library that comes to your mind.

This should lead to a wider range of choices when you look for mobile-browser-tailored solutions.